# How to preserve file permissions when using FileUtils.copyDirectory?

Tags: java, apache-commons

When I use `FileUtils.copyDirectory()`, the execute bits get turned off for executable files.
  Do I have to turn them on manually?

FWIW, my umask is set to 0027 but it looks like `FileUtils.copyDirectory()` is not using that setting since the 'other' permissions, aside from the execute bit, are preserved.

Comment: What operating system are you using? I wouldn't be surprised if behavior differs between Linux, FreeBSD and Mac OS X...

Comment: I'm on Linux.

Since I have a workaround, I'll wait until the adoption of Java 7 in my company.

Answer (score 8):

The upcoming Filesystem additions in Java 7 will help. Look at JSR-203. If you are using Linux, you can use the [backport](http://code.google.com/p/jsr203-backport/) with Java 6.

The new API that you want is: [`Files.copy(Path, Path, CopyOptions)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)). Note that `CopyOptions` has [`COPY_ATTRIBUTES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html#COPY_ATTRIBUTES), which will do what you want.

Comment: Using this API, if you copy a non-empty directory, it creates just an empty directory in the target `path`. Any workaround?

Comment: `COPY_ATTRIBUTES` doesn't work on all file systems. On a macOS, it throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think its possible because of JVM limitations. The IO api and behavior is kinda shameful for the most popular language/platform in the world.

If you look at the FileUtils source code, during copy it creates the new file like this

```
File copiedFile = new File(destDir, srcFile.getName());
```

the file permissions are not preserved. And during actual copy the bytes are copied in batches ( buffered ) and written to the new file.

but, you could wait a couple of days or use the preview release of JDK7 which has apis to allow this to be possible.